# MS Access Error: "External table not in the expected format" when trying to open linked table which previously worked

Tags: excel, ms-access, linked-tables

I have some queries in my Access database which pull data from Excel files that appear in the database as linked tables.  They have worked just fine, until suddenly and inexplicably I was getting the error "External table is not in the expected format," when trying to access them.

I thought it might have to do with the fact that I was using a macro-enabled workbook, but it was fine before.  I do have a mail merge set up in Word which is linked to the database, and using one of the aforementioned queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the issue was due to the mail merge document.  Once I saved and closed the mail merge file in Word and tried accessing the queries and tables again in Access, the error was no longer appearing.

It seems that if a Word mail merge is connected to the database, this error may appear.  I am not sure as to why a more appropriate error is not appearing; after testing it seems to happen regardless of whether the linked file is a macro-enabled workbook or not.

In short, as Olivier put it, the file was locked by Word.  A simple issue, but not exactly clear given the error message (unless you follow Andre's logic that the expected format is a non-locked file, hahah).

I hope this helps someone else!

Comment: It looks that I am unable to accept my own answer until two days have passed, so I will do so then, unless anyone else has anything more to add!

Comment: The file was locked by Word.

Comment: Right, that is what I was trying to say.  I just tested it with a regular workbook (not macro-enabled) and the same, inappropriate error appears... strange.  The error is very misleading and I did not find anyone in a similar situation in my searching, which is what prompted me to post this question & answer.

Comment: Well, the expected format is a **non-locked** excel file, one might argue... :)

Comment: Andre, a valid argument, I think, hahah!

Answer (score 0):

My form is hooked to a query.  The "not in expected format" message happens when the query is set up as a "snapshot".  When I changed to "dynaset", the form started to work as expected.